Error invoking function. status: 500 message: internal server error
I try to invoke a fn-project function (hello-world) locally on my MacOS(x86) but I get an error message:
# latest version of fnserver is running
docker container ls -fname=fnserver
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                       COMMAND        CREATED        STATUS        PORTS                              NAMES
2cedf81d3497   fnproject/fnserver:latest   "./fnserver"   44 hours ago   Up 44 hours   2375/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp   fnserver

# run
fn invoke example hello-world
Error invoking function. status: 500 message: internal server error

# what's in the logfile? 
docker container logs fnserver

time="2024-08-07T09:10:15Z" level=info msg="hot function failure" app_id=01J2G821EJNG8G00GZJ0000001 container_id=01J4P1MVJWNG8G00GZJ0000006 cpus= error="Container failed to initialize, please ensure you are using the latest fdk and check the logs" fn_id=01J2G838WENG8G00GZJ0000002 idle_timeout=30 image="hello-world:0.0.9" memory=512
time="2024-08-07T09:10:15Z" level=info msg="container wait error, sending error to client" action="server.handleFnInvokeCall)-fm" app_id=01J2G821EJNG8G00GZJ0000001 call_id=01J4P1MVJWNG8G00GZJ0000005 error="API error (400): You should always set the Memory limit when using Memoryswap limit, see usage" fn_id=01J2G838WENG8G00GZJ0000002
time="2024-08-07T09:10:15Z" level=error msg="internal server error" action="server.handleFnInvokeCall)-fm" error="API error (400): You should always set the Memory limit when using Memoryswap limit, see usage" fn_id=01J2G838WENG8G00GZJ0000002 stack="goroutine 55 [running]:\nruntime/debug.Stack(0xc42017b9d0, 0x10852c0, 0xc420170380)\n\t/usr/local/go/src/runtime/debug/stack.go:24 +0xa7\ngithub.com/fnproject/fn/api/server.HandleErrorResponse(0x10902a0, 0xc42018df20, 0x7f0b33f517b0, 0xc4200ee580, 0x10852c0, 0xc420170380)\n\t/go/src/github.com/fnproject/fn/api/server/error_response.go:57 +0x57f\ngithub.com/fnproject/fn/api/server.handleErrorResponse(0xc4200e
...

grep fdk requirements.txt
fdk>=0.1.74

I can run all kinds of containers, but this one gives me an error message.
Any help is much appreciated.

Hit the same error. @Bjarte: Could you figure this out?
